# how google ads refer to dynamic content?

Tags: google, google-adsense, google-ads, advertising

I have mobile app / site and I want to use google ads with method PPM (pay per impression)
I am changing the page content programmatically with java script .
so if the user navigate to new page I actually just change the content in the same page. 
1.Is there any problem with this by google? 
2. do i get paid for this content change like if page really navigate?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Considering how many websites are dynamically generating content on the web I see no reason they would penalize you or have it against their TOS if you dynamically generated content on a single page for an app. If the content is all updated and generated by real humans that's fine if you start updating content with a script i'm sure it'll be red flagged and your account suspended. You may want to contact AdSense to clarify, give them a rundown of how your app works.

Comment: ok,let say they allow it ,but how they can know each time the user "navigate"
if I am generating the content dynamically on the client.
maby I will need to remove their client link and then regenerated it like real page navigation? otherwise I cant see how they will know and pay for each "navigation"

Comment: Because new ads are displayed which means there is a new impression generated that to them should indicate the visitor has navigated.